# Sharepoint Office365 REST Python Client get users

Tags: python, sharepoint, properties, office365

I am trying to integrate SharePoint in one of my Python Scripts and I need to grab the users from a SP list. Until now, I managed to log in, search for a specific list, and enumerate all of its items.

```
def enum_items(list):
    items = list.items  # .top(1220)
    ctx.load(items)
    ctx.execute_query()
    for index, item in enumerate(items):
        print("{0}: {1}".format(index, item.properties['Email']))
```

The 'Email' column's value is set to User.email like so:

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "div",
   "txtContent": "[$User.email]"
}
```

Basically the Email is automatically set when a new user is added in the User column.

Some entries where manually added, and others use the above code. For those that were manually added it prints the email, but for the other, it prints: "None".

If I change the 'Email' to 'User', I get the following error, like it cannot find that column or so:

```
    print("{0}: {1}".format(index, item.properties['User']))
KeyError: 'User'
```

Is there anyway I can grab the USER object, and then use its properties (which ever those are) to grab some information about it?

Thanks!